# How to get audio spectrum analysis?

Tags: python, math

I need to find or create a tool that analyzes the audio spectrum of a sound file (like a .wav or .mp3). I need to output the "volume" or power of x number of frequency bands and output the data as text. This will be used to produce a visualization, a graphic equalizer like you'd see on a stereo.

I am currently looking at python to do it. My question is are there some tools out there that would do this (signal processing), like math works or others? I don't have any experience with them so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with an Internet Search for "Audio spectral analysis python".

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Robert Harvey's comment, you'll want to look for a `Fast Fourier Transform` with python.

There is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604453/1345223) that discusses the output from one of the algorithms and how to interpret it.

Here's the [numpy module](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.fft.fftpack.html) which came up second in my search.  So it looks like you shouldn't need to do much coding at all.

[This link](http://vibrationdata.com/python-wiki/index.php?title=Fourier_Transform) will point you to some other implementations.

And here's a [wordpress blog](http://jeremykun.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/the-fast-fourier-transform/) that provides some background on the FFT as well as using the [numpy module](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.fft.fftpack.html).

And as [jk](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/10563/jk) points out: "you may need a [Window Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) as well to smooth out spectral leakage."

Comment: you may need a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function as well to smooth out spectral leakage

Comment: @jk. - good point, and I've updated my answer accordingly.  Thanks!